# Xamarin.forms Data passing to another view

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have problem with passing parameter of ListView(Data Json Response) to Detailview. In listview i showed name of the title, and i want to show some details in DetailView. here the problem i can`t get index value of set of JSOn Value to pass Detail view.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you use ListView and select an Item, you have SelectedItem property with the selected value. Pass SelectedItem to your DetailView. It's enough

Comment: I can access only one value not list of value. 

What i really trying for 

  [ {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur"
  },   

in Listview i showed UserId and when i click userID it navigating to DetailView with USED ID not entire list. i am not able to pass entire list  to detail view. Can you help me

Comment: Post your code when you do PushAsync... it should be something like Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(PageAViewModel));

Comment: foreach (var data in objResponse1)
                {
                    listModel.ASSET_NO = data.ASSET_NO;
                    listModel.Asset_Owner = data.Asset_Owner;
                    listModel.Image_count = data.Image_count;
                    listModel.vendor = data.vendor;
                }
    private void assetListPage_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new AssetListDetailViewPage(listModel));
    }    I am using the same ways but  what i need to do when i access in detailview.

Comment: you have to pass the index of the selected item, or the selecteditem and modify listModel[idx]